# Showing a loading graphic in cocos2d which does not lag or stutter

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

In several cases, I want to show some sort of loading graphic/screen while my cocos2d iPhone game is getting ready. For example, it might be creating `CCSprite` objects in the `init` method of a new scene, caching textures via `[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:fnTexture];`, etc.

Unfortunately, all these operations need to run on the cocos display thread. This means that any attempt I make to create some nice animations (e.g., a spinning graphic) essentially lock up while the thread is working, and my pretty animations freeze.

I can think of three possible solutions...

1. Insert artificial delays between the expensive operations, giving my animation time to update. Unfortunately this still leads to jittery animations, and definitely reeks of "code smell."
2. Somehow create a 2nd cocos2d rendering thread, short lived, for the animation...? I can't find any documentation on if this is possible.
3. Use a plain old `UIView` pasted overtop my `OpenGL` view, which is of course running on the main thread and thus not subject to these constraints... however, this would require figuring out how to code my pretty animations into `UIKit`

Is #2 possible? Or... is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: There's also addImageAsync: which loads textures in the background. Only if you have other resource files besides textures that take a significant time to load I would use a non-cocos2d animation running on a separate thread, basically a UIKit progress indicator works just fine.

Comment: Nice, I somehow missed the async methods on the texture loading. This definitely helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, solution #3 did not work, because cocos2d on the iPhone actually uses the main thread for the cocos2d thread (however, this solution would work on OSX, because it uses a separate thread for cocos2d).

My eventual solution was based upon the reply from @LearnCocos2D (above).
First, using `addImageAsync:` eliminated most of the main-thread locking. The remaining lag had to do with creating `CCNode` objects (eg, `CCSprite`s). I used a variation on solution #1 to create a cache of pre-built cocos objects in my loader class, which could then be reused later on (eg, while rendering layers) to prevent needing to allocate objects at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

look MBProgressHUD on git. I did a quick test like so (took 3 minutes to put that in my game) :

```
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [[[MBProgressHUD alloc] init] autorelease];

    hud.xOffset = kScreenWidth / 2;
    hud.yOffset = kScreenHeight / 2;
    hud.progress = .5;
    [hud show:YES];
    [hud setTaskInProgress:YES];
    hud.labelText = @"Loading";

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].view addSubview:hud];
```

giving me this :

[image]

it animates superbly through some pretty intense texture preloads and scene setup/computations. You can figure out the 'how to integrate' in your app ... API is nice (delegate, etc...)

Comment: Essentially, what you're saying is to do #3 from my possible solutions in the question. As I explained in the question, I don't really want to do this, because I have very custom animations (and frankly MBProgress looks like crap). But, if that's the only solution, then I'll go ahead and code my loading views into UIKit.

Comment: lol, i dont do aesthetic evaluation ... but yes. option 3 is the only workable way i found of doing this without getting too involved into creating a custom. Since you are beached on the main thread with cocos2d ... well you know, had to figure out a way of stepping out' and getting some juice out of my devices. My preference would be for a rotating sword ... but alas mr Marketroid want the game out now,now,now :) ... best of luck.